# Создание процедур обработки событий в Excel

Tags: excel, макросы, макрос

1. В редакторе VBA создать процедуру обработки события Open объекта Workbook, генерируемого при открытии книги.
2. В редакторе VBA создать процедуру обработки события BeforeClose объекта Workbook, генерируемого перед  закрытием книги.

Answer (score 0):

Просто откройте модуль книги и воспользуйтесь двумя выпадающими списками над окном редактирования кода

[image: СобытияКниги.gif]